How do you make layouts flexible via Jetpack Compose?
This is from "Flexible layouts" of the Screen Compatibility Overview page in the Android's Developer Guide:

By default, Android resizes your app layout to fit the current screen. To help your layout resize well for small variations in screen size, implement your layout with flexibility in mind. Don't hardcode the position and size of your UI components. Instead, let view sizes stretch and specify view positions relative to the parent view or other sibling views so that your intended order and relative sizes remain the same as the layout grows.

How is it possible for me to not hard code some UI components?
How can I set the height and width of a card, for example, without doing that?
When I look at the Android official examples they are using hard coded values. What is the proper way to handle components size for screen compatibility?
I have read the Android Developer's Guide, reached out in the Android Discord help section, and have scoured Stack Overflow and other sites.


How is it possible for me to not hard code some UI components?

First, the documentation states you should avoid hardcoded values for setting size or position of a Composable. However, hardcoded values are not inherently wrong, as it is totally fine to use hardcoded values to set padding between two Composables.
In my experience, you can always avoid hardcoded values for setting a Composable's position. But there are situations where you might have to use hardcoded values to set a height or width.

When you have a vertically scrollable Composable and want to set the height of the items to be the same, independently of the height of the individual item's content.

When you have a horizontally scrollable Composable and want to set the width of the items to be the same, independently of the width of the individual item's content

When you have an Image Composable, you will typically set a fixed size, as there is no point in having a huge Image on tablets and a mini Image on small smartphones


Jetpack Compose offers you many ways to position Composables without any hardcoded values. You can find them by inspecting the parameters of the respective Composable function. I added an example of how you should and not should do it for a Column.
DON'T
@Composable
fun SizingPitfalls() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            // using hardcoded value to center horizontally - DON'T
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 145.dp),
            text = "TOP CENTER"
        )
        Text(
            // using hardcoded value to center vertically and align to end - DON'T
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 275.dp, top = 330.dp),
            text = "MIDDLE END"
        )
        Text(
            // using hardcoded value to align to bottom and end - DON'T
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 130.dp, top = 330.dp),
            text = "BOTTOM CENTER"
        )
    }
}

 
DO
@Composable
fun PositioningGoodies() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        // use available params for relatively positioning child Composables
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "TOP CENTER"
        )
        Text(
            // use predefined Modifier to override parent setting
            // to relatively place Composable somewhere else
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End),
            text = "MIDDLE END"
        )
        Text(
            text = "BOTTOM CENTER"
        )
    }
}

 

You can see that the first approach completely breaks once the screen is rotated, as we used absolute values to position our Composables.
